# error BrowserlistsError from create-react-app npm run-script build

Tags: reactjs

I created a project using the cli utility create-react-app.
When i use the npm start, all works as expected.

But when i try to run "npm run-script build" i get the error below:

`./src/index.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query 'dead'
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)`

I have the folowing structure of the package.json

```
`{
  "name": "site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}`
```

It builds if i remove the "not dead" , but i feel like i am creating some future problems. Do somebody got this error ? Knows the workaround, do i have to worry about taking off this ?

Answer (score 1):

Temporary Solution :
make browserlist as empty

`{
  "name": "site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": []
}`